# Move vue-particles component to the back and use it as the background

Tags: css, vue.js, particles.js

I want the Vue-Particles component to be at the back, but somehow I cannot make this to work. All my components and HTML tags are behind the particles.

What I've tried is to fix it using the `z-index` CSS property.

Using `z-index: 0` on the particle-js component:

```
h1 {
  z-index: 999;
}

#particles-js { 
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Shows like this:

[image: problem 1]

Using `z-index: -1` on the particle-js component moves the component to the bottom, not to the background like I want. See the new problem here:

[image: Problem 2]

EDIT: All my code is here, I am using Bootstrap-vue also:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar />
    <vue-particles color="#e60000"></vue-particles>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navbar
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;

}

h1 {
  z-index: 999;
}

#particles-js { 
  /*position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  z-index: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0; 
}


</style>
```

The effect I want is something like this, where the lines don't cover anything of the title:

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: Based on the minimal information in the post, it looks like it's working to me. Could you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephenThomas I want the `h1` not to be covered by the lines of the particles.

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky). The `h1` should have one of this position to be above particles

Comment: Thanks Calean! That was the issue I believe. We finally got it working: http://data-me.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overlap text divs and vue-particle by setting the the text div position as `absolute` and specifying vertical and horizontal positioning. For example, to place something in the middle of the screen on top of the particles:

#### html:

```html
<vue-particles color="#dedede"></vue-particles>
<div class="centered-text">
  <p> Hello World </p>
</div>
```

#### css:

```css
#particles-js {
  height: 100vh;
}

.centered-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Great try! We end up using a different approach but the result is the same: http://data-me.herokuapp.com